# Invald parameter "service=" nginx conf

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Trying to configure nginx and everything seems to work besides when I assign a service to one of the upstream server...

Do i need to explicitly reference what SRV record I want to use with this server to begin with because I'm copying directly from godaddy?

The error stems from `server gife.gi-me.app service=https resolve;`

nginx.conf ->

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

# Load Balancer
    server {
        listen      8081;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            root /resource;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_pass_request_body on;
            proxy_buffering off;
            resolver 172.16.0.23;
            proxy_pass http://finalmvploadbalancer; 
        }
    }

# Group of servers -> access http://finalmvploadbalancer 
    upstream finalmvploadbalancer {
        # server balance.gi-me.app service=balance resolve;
        # server balance.gi-me.app service=balances resolve;
        # server balance2.gi-me.app service=balance2 resolve;
        # server balance2.gi-me.app service=balances2 resolve;
          server gife.gi-me.app service=https resolve;
    }

    # HTTPS server
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  gife.gi-me.app;

        ssl_certificate      /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/finalmvp/finalmvpssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/finalmvp/gifeappserver2.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        ## OCSP Stapling
        resolver 127.0.0.1;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/finalmvp/finalmvpssl-bundle.crt;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
    include servers/*;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the commercial version of Nginx?

Comment: nope only the free version, should I be using the commercial version if I'm specifying services? @RichardSmith